# ssh how stop Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-keys

In every process SSH return Permission denied (publickey).

```
ssh-copy-id root@XXX.XXX.XX.XX
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: 4 key(s) remain to be installed -- if you are prompted now it is to install the new keys
Permission denied (publickey).


ssh root@XXX.XXX.XX.XX
Permission denied (publickey).
```

When i try using -vvv then return

```
debug1: Trying private key: /home/leo/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/leo/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/leo/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/leo/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/leo/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/leo/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

How to stop SSH Permission denied (publickey) and connect to host server?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like on your server you only can login with a key, not with password.

If your public key on the server site is added to  `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` then you should be able to login with `ssh root@xxx.xx.xx.xx -i /path/to/key`

If you don't have a key, you could follow this steps:

1. on your client run `ssh-keygen`, by default the key is created ath ~/.ssh/id_rsa
2. There also is a `id_rsa.pub` created. Copy that line in `id_rsa.pub` and add it on the server to `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`
3. Login to your server with `ssh root@xxx.xx.xx.xx -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: copy id_rsa or id_rsa.pub which file copy on the server please specify me

Comment: I changed my answer at number 2, I had a typo. You have to copy the line from `id_rsa.pub` to the `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` of your server.

Comment: is there any best way to write this file on server console? cause i can not copy paste

Comment: how do you connect to your server? Actually you could copy the file with scp (but since you can't login with ssh, this would not work). You could copy your public key on an ftp-server and download it from the server.

Comment: i have no ssh so can not able to create ftp-server

Comment: can i create ftp account from root user or console

Comment: My idea was, if you own a FTP server, you could upload it there. Or if you have a own website, you could upload it there and then download it with `wget example.com/my-key.pub`. And if you don't have any of this, then I think it's the fastest if you manually type the key on your server.