# New user gets permission denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, permissions

After creating a new user and granting sudo power to it, it gets permission denied.

I am the root, logging in as ubuntu@nameserver, when I try to login with the user i created to myself, I get permission denied (public key)

The steps I followed:

```
root@nameserver#  adduser newuser
root@nameserver#  usermod -aG sudo newuser
```

After:

```
ubuntu@thapp:~$ ssh -vvv newuser@nameserver
```

I get:

```
 Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
newuser@nameserver: Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have seen many posts provide a variety of commands, but they haven't been clear as to how to use them.

ie.:

> It looks like on your server you only can login with a key, not with password.

> If your public key on the server site is added to /root/.ssh/authorized_keys then you >should be able to login with ssh root@xxx.xx.xx.xx -i /path/to/key

> ref.: [latest Superuser post](https://superuser.com/questions/1270144/ssh-how-stop-permission-denied-publickey)

How do I know the /path-to-key?

Even logged as root:

```
ubuntu@nameserver:~$ /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
-bash: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys: Permission denied
ubuntu@nameserver:~$ sudo su
root@nameserver:/home/ubuntu# /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
bash: /root/.ssh/authorized_keys: Permission denied
root@nameserver:/home/ubuntu#
```

Please instruct the command with an example I can follow and how I should be logged. I have both the private and public keys of the instance downloaded to my local pc, I login with Putty and use the key alone to access it.

Best.

Answer (score 0):

please google: "How To Configure SSH Key-Based Authentication"
btw you got permission denied, because you try to run that file.
try: `cat /root/.ssh/authorized_keys`
and if you want to login with the same key as the root has, but with the user ubuntu:

```
mkdir ~ubuntu/.ssh
cp /root/.ssh/authorized_keys ~ubuntu/.ssh
chown -R ubuntu: ~ubuntu/.ssh
chmod 700 ~ubuntu/.ssh
chmod 600 ~ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Comment: thanks, after running this commands I moved on with the install.